# map::erase: difference between erase by key or by iterator?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

If I want to remove a single element from a map (and I don't care about the return value apart from possibly error checking), there are two ways that I could it: `erase` by key or `erase` by value:

http://ideone.com/YWocN7

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void printMap(const std::map<int, double>& m)
{
    for (auto kv : m)
    {
        std::cout << '{' << kv.first << ", " << kv.second << '}';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "erase by iterator:\n";
    std::map<int, double> m1 = { { 1, 1.1 }, { 2, 2.2 }, { 3, 3.3 } };
    printMap(m1);
    m1.erase(m1.find(2));
    printMap(m1);

    std::cout << "erase by key:\n";
    std::map<int, double> m2 = { { 1, 1.1 }, { 2, 2.2 }, { 3, 3.3 } };
    printMap(m2);
    m2.erase(2);
    printMap(m2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
erase by iterator:
{1, 1.1}{2, 2.2}{3, 3.3}
{1, 1.1}{3, 3.3}
erase by key:
{1, 1.1}{2, 2.2}{3, 3.3}
{1, 1.1}{3, 3.3}
```

Are the two methods **entirely equivalent**, or is there any practical reason or situation where I might **prefer one over the other**?

Comment: Erasing by iterator should be slightly faster since it doesn't have to walk down the tree looking for the key first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the scenario you describe (`m1.erase(2);` vs. `m1.erase(m1.find(2));`), the two methods are should be entirely equivalent, give or take the cost of creating and returning iterators, though this depends on your STL implementation.
The point of `erase by iterator` is to remove an entry from the key, when you already have an iterator because of other operations your program needed to execute on the element this iterator refers to. For instance:

```
void processEntry(const std::pair<int, double>& p) {
     // do something like maybe writing it to a file
}

std::map<int, double> m1 = { { 1, 1.1 }, { 2, 2.2 }, { 3, 3.3 } };

const auto it = std::find_if(m1.begin(), m1.end(), [](const std::pair<int, double>& p) {
    return p.first > 1 && p.second < 3.0;
});

if (it != m1.end()) {
    processEntry(*it);
    m1.erase(it);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Map erase supports erasing elemnt(s) in different ways as below

```
void erase( iterator pos );
iterator erase( const_iterator pos );
void erase( iterator first, iterator last );
iterator erase( const_iterator first, const_iterator last );        
size_type erase( const key_type& key );
```

In you case you are using erase( iterator) and erase( const key_type) even though result of both the operation is same how the operation is executed might be different.

`erase( const key_type& key );` will find the key and then erase it.

`erase( iterator)` already has the position which wants to erase the element